# Angular MongoDB Express Giving Error Duplicate Key Error

Tags: angular, mongodb, express

In my service I wrote some code to add in size when the user want to add a product to cart.
The reason for this is I did not want to add a size in the product data.  I do have the property in database but the value is empty (size: " "), so I wrote a snippet of code Object.defineProperty()  which modifies an existing property on the object. It gives me two request with an error   It worked on my ***fake backend** even though I got two request it posted the second one. In http request I'm getting a error regarding duplicate key,   now both request are pending.  I can't figure out why.

The user chooses size based on radio button then clicks add to cart, my service is then called which make my http request, in the debugger there is are two request

code snippet of my service:

```
    addProductToCart(products:Products,             
   _id:String,Valuesize:string):Observable<Products>{


     Object.defineProperties(products,{
        size:{
        value: Valuesize,
        writable: false
      }

  });



 return this.http.post<any>(this.rootUrl + '/getProducts/addtocart' + _id,  {products})
```

}

//I'm doing a simple insert into database
Snippet below:

```
  router.post('/getProducts/addtocart:id',   async(req, res)=> {

    const _id = req.params.id;
    const cartItem = await Products.findById({_id:_id})
 
       mongoose.connect(mongoURI, function(err, db){
         assert.ok("1" == 1 );
         db.collection('carts').insertOne(cartItem, function(err, result){
    
           if(err) {
             console.log(err)
             }
           else{
           res.send(result).status(200);
            }
              console.log("I document inserted");
        })    

     });

  });
```

It worked fine on my fake back end when adding data to a json file. Did some research
with no luck but I'm still searching. not sure why there are two request.  Could some one
point me in the right direction it
would be greatly appreciate

Thanking you in advance,
PDH